Paper by Dmitriev and Dynkin on 'pre-Karpeleciv's' bound
There is a relatively well-known paper by N. Dmitriev and E. Dynkin, published in 1946 [1], where they discussed a geometrical perspective on what is now known as the 'Karpelevic bound' on the eigenvalues of stochastic matrices [2] (Karpelevic published a complete proof in 1951).
A year before, Dmitriev and Dynkin published a short paper on the same topic [3]. This earlier paper is rather obscure, and I have been unable to locate it. However, it seems to contain some important statements, specifically regarding the relationship between generators and stochastic matrices, which are not present in their 1946 publication.
Does anyone have access to this paper? If so, could you share it with me? Alternatively, could you direct me to a source where I might find it?
A brief history of my quest for the paper: It is mentioned in a paper [4] and a presentation [5] by Ádám Besenyei [6]. In the latter, he even references some results from [3]. I tried to contact him using two email addresses I found, but both emails were returned with "could not be delivered because the email does not exist." Today I discovered that Besenyei passed away in December 2022 [7]. In his paper [4], Besenyei thanks "Craig Smoryński for sending a copy of the paper" (which is the paper by Dmitriev and Dynkin in question). Smoryński has published numerous books on various mathematical topics, but it seems he retired quite a while ago, and it is unclear if he is still alive.
[1] N. Dmitriev, E. Dynkin, On characteristic roots of stochastic matrices Izv.
Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat., 10 (1946), 167-184.
[2] see, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.03849
[3] N. Dmitriev, E. Dynkin, On the characteristic roots of stochastic matrices,
C. R. (Doklady) Acad. Sci. URSS, 49 (1945), 159–162.
[4] https://abesenyei.web.elte.hu/publications/dynkingem.pdf
[5] https://abesenyei.web.elte.hu/publications/dynkin.pdf
[6] https://abesenyei.web.elte.hu/eng/index_eng.php
[7] http://www.arpadgimnazium.hu/elhunyt-dr-besenyei-adam-tanar-ur/
[8] https://www.amazon.com/Books-Craig-Smorynski/s?rh=n%3A283155%2Cp_27%3ACraig+Smorynski
